# how to disallow update specific field in firestore document via security rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have an event document that consist of fields like title, location, capacity, coordinate etc. I want to set security rules that allow to update a document but will reject the request if the user trying to change capacity field

so how to write security rules like that ? can I do that ?

```
service cloud.firestore {
    function admin() {
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true
    }
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /events/{eventId} {

              allow update: if // (allow if user not trying to update capacity field) ???
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the contents of the requested document update to the existing contents to make sure it didn't change:

```
allow update: if request.resource.data.capacity == resource.data.capacity;
```

[request.resource](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#resource) is the document of the incoming request.  [resource](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource) is the existing data.